# You're going to laugh, but the nonzero integers have a natural group law using multiplication and gcd formula (no addition!)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, integers

See: [the associativity of $\gcd(a,b)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Lattice-theoretic).

So this means the following operation:

$$
a \star b := \dfrac{ ab}{\gcd(a,b)^2}
$$

is such that:

$$
a \star (b \star c) = a \star \dfrac{bc}{\gcd(b,c)^2} = \dfrac {abc}{\gcd(a, \frac{bc}{\gcd(b,c)^2})^2} = \\
(a\star b)\star c
$$

The following code verifies associativity:

```
from sympy import *

N = 10
for a in range(-N, N):
   if a != 0:         
      for b in range(-N, N):
         if b != 0:               
            for c in range (-N, N):
               if c != 0:                     
                  assert ((a * b // (gcd(a,b)**2)) * c) // (gcd(a*b // (gcd(a,b)**2), c)**2)
                  
                  print(f'{a}*({b}*{c}) = ({a}*{b})*{c}')

-10*(-10*-10) = (-10*-10)*-10
-10*(-10*-9) = (-10*-10)*-9
-10*(-10*-8) = (-10*-10)*-8
-10*(-10*-7) = (-10*-10)*-7
-10*(-10*-6) = (-10*-10)*-6
-10*(-10*-5) = (-10*-10)*-5
-10*(-10*-4) = (-10*-10)*-4
-10*(-10*-3) = (-10*-10)*-3
-10*(-10*-2) = (-10*-10)*-2
-10*(-10*-1) = (-10*-10)*-1
-10*(-10*1) = (-10*-10)*1
-10*(-10*2) = (-10*-10)*2
-10*(-10*3) = (-10*-10)*3
-10*(-10*4) = (-10*-10)*4
-10*(-10*5) = (-10*-10)*5
-10*(-10*6) = (-10*-10)*6
-10*(-10*7) = (-10*-10)*7
-10*(-10*8) = (-10*-10)*8
-10*(-10*9) = (-10*-10)*9
-10*(-9*-10) = (-10*-9)*-10
-10*(-9*-9) = (-10*-9)*-9
-10*(-9*-8) = (-10*-9)*-8
-10*(-9*-7) = (-10*-9)*-7
-10*(-9*-6) = (-10*-9)*-6
-10*(-9*-5) = (-10*-9)*-5
-10*(-9*-4) = (-10*-9)*-4
-10*(-9*-3) = (-10*-9)*-3
-10*(-9*-2) = (-10*-9)*-2
-10*(-9*-1) = (-10*-9)*-1
-10*(-9*1) = (-10*-9)*1
-10*(-9*2) = (-10*-9)*2
-10*(-9*3) = (-10*-9)*3
-10*(-9*4) = (-10*-9)*4
-10*(-9*5) = (-10*-9)*5
-10*(-9*6) = (-10*-9)*6
-10*(-9*7) = (-10*-9)*7
-10*(-9*8) = (-10*-9)*8
-10*(-9*9) = (-10*-9)*9
-10*(-8*-10) = (-10*-8)*-10
-10*(-8*-9) = (-10*-8)*-9
-10*(-8*-8) = (-10*-8)*-8
-10*(-8*-7) = (-10*-8)*-7
-10*(-8*-6) = (-10*-8)*-6
-10*(-8*-5) = (-10*-8)*-5
-10*(-8*-4) = (-10*-8)*-4
-10*(-8*-3) = (-10*-8)*-3
-10*(-8*-2) = (-10*-8)*-2
-10*(-8*-1) = (-10*-8)*-1
-10*(-8*1) = (-10*-8)*1
-10*(-8*2) = (-10*-8)*2
-10*(-8*3) = (-10*-8)*3
-10*(-8*4) = (-10*-8)*4
-10*(-8*5) = (-10*-8)*5
-10*(-8*6) = (-10*-8)*6
-10*(-8*7) = (-10*-8)*7
-10*(-8*8) = (-10*-8)*8
-10*(-8*9) = (-10*-8)*9
-10*(-7*-10) = (-10*-7)*-10
-10*(-7*-9) = (-10*-7)*-9
-10*(-7*-8) = (-10*-7)*-8
-10*(-7*-7) = (-10*-7)*-7
-10*(-7*-6) = (-10*-7)*-6
-10*(-7*-5) = (-10*-7)*-5
-10*(-7*-4) = (-10*-7)*-4
-10*(-7*-3) = (-10*-7)*-3
-10*(-7*-2) = (-10*-7)*-2
-10*(-7*-1) = (-10*-7)*-1
-10*(-7*1) = (-10*-7)*1
-10*(-7*2) = (-10*-7)*2
-10*(-7*3) = (-10*-7)*3
-10*(-7*4) = (-10*-7)*4
-10*(-7*5) = (-10*-7)*5
-10*(-7*6) = (-10*-7)*6
-10*(-7*7) = (-10*-7)*7
-10*(-7*8) = (-10*-7)*8
-10*(-7*9) = (-10*-7)*9
-10*(-6*-10) = (-10*-6)*-10
-10*(-6*-9) = (-10*-6)*-9
-10*(-6*-8) = (-10*-6)*-8
-10*(-6*-7) = (-10*-6)*-7
-10*(-6*-6) = (-10*-6)*-6
-10*(-6*-5) = (-10*-6)*-5
-10*(-6*-4) = (-10*-6)*-4
-10*(-6*-3) = (-10*-6)*-3
-10*(-6*-2) = (-10*-6)*-2
-10*(-6*-1) = (-10*-6)*-1
-10*(-6*1) = (-10*-6)*1
-10*(-6*2) = (-10*-6)*2
-10*(-6*3) = (-10*-6)*3
-10*(-6*4) = (-10*-6)*4
-10*(-6*5) = (-10*-6)*5
-10*(-6*6) = (-10*-6)*6
-10*(-6*7) = (-10*-6)*7
-10*(-6*8) = (-10*-6)*8
-10*(-6*9) = (-10*-6)*9
-10*(-5*-10) = (-10*-5)*-10
-10*(-5*-9) = (-10*-5)*-9
-10*(-5*-8) = (-10*-5)*-8
-10*(-5*-7) = (-10*-5)*-7
-10*(-5*-6) = (-10*-5)*-6
-10*(-5*-5) = (-10*-5)*-5
-10*(-5*-4) = (-10*-5)*-4
-10*(-5*-3) = (-10*-5)*-3
-10*(-5*-2) = (-10*-5)*-2
-10*(-5*-1) = (-10*-5)*-1
-10*(-5*1) = (-10*-5)*1
-10*(-5*2) = (-10*-5)*2
-10*(-5*3) = (-10*-5)*3
-10*(-5*4) = (-10*-5)*4
-10*(-5*5) = (-10*-5)*5
-10*(-5*6) = (-10*-5)*6
-10*(-5*7) = (-10*-5)*7
-10*(-5*8) = (-10*-5)*8
-10*(-5*9) = (-10*-5)*9
-10*(-4*-10) = (-10*-4)*-10
-10*(-4*-9) = (-10*-4)*-9
-10*(-4*-8) = (-10*-4)*-8
-10*(-4*-7) = (-10*-4)*-7
-10*(-4*-6) = (-10*-4)*-6
-10*(-4*-5) = (-10*-4)*-5
-10*(-4*-4) = (-10*-4)*-4
-10*(-4*-3) = (-10*-4)*-3
-10*(-4*-2) = (-10*-4)*-2
-10*(-4*-1) = (-10*-4)*-1
-10*(-4*1) = (-10*-4)*1
-10*(-4*2) = (-10*-4)*2
-10*(-4*3) = (-10*-4)*3
-10*(-4*4) = (-10*-4)*4
-10*(-4*5) = (-10*-4)*5
-10*(-4*6) = (-10*-4)*6
-10*(-4*7) = (-10*-4)*7
-10*(-4*8) = (-10*-4)*8
-10*(-4*9) = (-10*-4)*9
-10*(-3*-10) = (-10*-3)*-10
-10*(-3*-9) = (-10*-3)*-9
-10*(-3*-8) = (-10*-3)*-8
-10*(-3*-7) = (-10*-3)*-7
-10*(-3*-6) = (-10*-3)*-6
-10*(-3*-5) = (-10*-3)*-5
-10*(-3*-4) = (-10*-3)*-4
-10*(-3*-3) = (-10*-3)*-3
-10*(-3*-2) = (-10*-3)*-2
-10*(-3*-1) = (-10*-3)*-1
-10*(-3*1) = (-10*-3)*1
-10*(-3*2) = (-10*-3)*2
-10*(-3*3) = (-10*-3)*3
-10*(-3*4) = (-10*-3)*4
-10*(-3*5) = (-10*-3)*5
-10*(-3*6) = (-10*-3)*6
-10*(-3*7) = (-10*-3)*7
-10*(-3*8) = (-10*-3)*8
-10*(-3*9) = (-10*-3)*9
-10*(-2*-10) = (-10*-2)*-10
-10*(-2*-9) = (-10*-2)*-9
-10*(-2*-8) = (-10*-2)*-8
-10*(-2*-7) = (-10*-2)*-7
-10*(-2*-6) = (-10*-2)*-6
-10*(-2*-5) = (-10*-2)*-5
-10*(-2*-4) = (-10*-2)*-4
-10*(-2*-3) = (-10*-2)*-3
-10*(-2*-2) = (-10*-2)*-2
-10*(-2*-1) = (-10*-2)*-1
-10*(-2*1) = (-10*-2)*1
-10*(-2*2) = (-10*-2)*2
-10*(-2*3) = (-10*-2)*3
-10*(-2*4) = (-10*-2)*4
-10*(-2*5) = (-10*-2)*5
-10*(-2*6) = (-10*-2)*6
-10*(-2*7) = (-10*-2)*7
-10*(-2*8) = (-10*-2)*8
-10*(-2*9) = (-10*-2)*9
-10*(-1*-10) = (-10*-1)*-10
-10*(-1*-9) = (-10*-1)*-9
-10*(-1*-8) = (-10*-1)*-8
-10*(-1*-7) = (-10*-1)*-7
-10*(-1*-6) = (-10*-1)*-6
-10*(-1*-5) = (-10*-1)*-5
-10*(-1*-4) = (-10*-1)*-4
-10*(-1*-3) = (-10*-1)*-3
-10*(-1*-2) = (-10*-1)*-2
-10*(-1*-1) = (-10*-1)*-1
-10*(-1*1) = (-10*-1)*1
-10*(-1*2) = (-10*-1)*2
-10*(-1*3) = (-10*-1)*3
-10*(-1*4) = (-10*-1)*4
-10*(-1*5) = (-10*-1)*5
-10*(-1*6) = (-10*-1)*6
-10*(-1*7) = (-10*-1)*7
-10*(-1*8) = (-10*-1)*8
-10*(-1*9) = (-10*-1)*9
-10*(1*-10) = (-10*1)*-10
-10*(1*-9) = (-10*1)*-9
-10*(1*-8) = (-10*1)*-8
-10*(1*-7) = (-10*1)*-7
-10*(1*-6) = (-10*1)*-6
-10*(1*-5) = (-10*1)*-5
-10*(1*-4) = (-10*1)*-4
-10*(1*-3) = (-10*1)*-3
-10*(1*-2) = (-10*1)*-2
-10*(1*-1) = (-10*1)*-1
-10*(1*1) = (-10*1)*1
-10*(1*2) = (-10*1)*2
-10*(1*3) = (-10*1)*3
-10*(1*4) = (-10*1)*4
-10*(1*5) = (-10*1)*5
-10*(1*6) = (-10*1)*6
-10*(1*7) = (-10*1)*7
-10*(1*8) = (-10*1)*8
-10*(1*9) = (-10*1)*9
-10*(2*-10) = (-10*2)*-10
-10*(2*-9) = (-10*2)*-9
-10*(2*-8) = (-10*2)*-8
-10*(2*-7) = (-10*2)*-7
-10*(2*-6) = (-10*2)*-6
-10*(2*-5) = (-10*2)*-5
-10*(2*-4) = (-10*2)*-4
-10*(2*-3) = (-10*2)*-3
-10*(2*-2) = (-10*2)*-2
-10*(2*-1) = (-10*2)*-1
-10*(2*1) = (-10*2)*1
-10*(2*2) = (-10*2)*2
-10*(2*3) = (-10*2)*3
-10*(2*4) = (-10*2)*4
-10*(2*5) = (-10*2)*5
-10*(2*6) = (-10*2)*6
-10*(2*7) = (-10*2)*7
-10*(2*8) = (-10*2)*8
-10*(2*9) = (-10*2)*9
-10*(3*-10) = (-10*3)*-10
-10*(3*-9) = (-10*3)*-9
-10*(3*-8) = (-10*3)*-8
-10*(3*-7) = (-10*3)*-7
-10*(3*-6) = (-10*3)*-6
-10*(3*-5) = (-10*3)*-5
-10*(3*-4) = (-10*3)*-4
-10*(3*-3) = (-10*3)*-3
-10*(3*-2) = (-10*3)*-2
-10*(3*-1) = (-10*3)*-1
-10*(3*1) = (-10*3)*1
-10*(3*2) = (-10*3)*2
-10*(3*3) = (-10*3)*3
-10*(3*4) = (-10*3)*4
-10*(3*5) = (-10*3)*5
-10*(3*6) = (-10*3)*6
-10*(3*7) = (-10*3)*7
-10*(3*8) = (-10*3)*8
-10*(3*9) = (-10*3)*9
-10*(4*-10) = (-10*4)*-10
-10*(4*-9) = (-10*4)*-9
-10*(4*-8) = (-10*4)*-8
-10*(4*-7) = (-10*4)*-7
-10*(4*-6) = (-10*4)*-6
-10*(4*-5) = (-10*4)*-5
-10*(4*-4) = (-10*4)*-4
-10*(4*-3) = (-10*4)*-3
-10*(4*-2) = (-10*4)*-2
-10*(4*-1) = (-10*4)*-1
-10*(4*1) = (-10*4)*1
-10*(4*2) = (-10*4)*2
-10*(4*3) = (-10*4)*3
-10*(4*4) = (-10*4)*4
-10*(4*5) = (-10*4)*5
-10*(4*6) = (-10*4)*6
-10*(4*7) = (-10*4)*7
-10*(4*8) = (-10*4)*8
-10*(4*9) = (-10*4)*9
-10*(5*-10) = (-10*5)*-10
-10*(5*-9) = (-10*5)*-9
-10*(5*-8) = (-10*5)*-8
-10*(5*-7) = (-10*5)*-7
-10*(5*-6) = (-10*5)*-6
-10*(5*-5) = (-10*5)*-5
-10*(5*-4) = (-10*5)*-4
-10*(5*-3) = (-10*5)*-3
-10*(5*-2) = (-10*5)*-2
-10*(5*-1) = (-10*5)*-1
-10*(5*1) = (-10*5)*1
-10*(5*2) = (-10*5)*2
-10*(5*3) = (-10*5)*3
-10*(5*4) = (-10*5)*4
-10*(5*5) = (-10*5)*5
-10*(5*6) = (-10*5)*6
-10*(5*7) = (-10*5)*7
-10*(5*8) = (-10*5)*8
-10*(5*9) = (-10*5)*9
-10*(6*-10) = (-10*6)*-10
-10*(6*-9) = (-10*6)*-9
-10*(6*-8) = (-10*6)*-8
-10*(6*-7) = (-10*6)*-7
-10*(6*-6) = (-10*6)*-6
-10*(6*-5) = (-10*6)*-5
-10*(6*-4) = (-10*6)*-4
-10*(6*-3) = (-10*6)*-3
-10*(6*-2) = (-10*6)*-2
-10*(6*-1) = (-10*6)*-1
-10*(6*1) = (-10*6)*1
-10*(6*2) = (-10*6)*2
-10*(6*3) = (-10*6)*3
-10*(6*4) = (-10*6)*4
-10*(6*5) = (-10*6)*5
-10*(6*6) = (-10*6)*6
-10*(6*7) = (-10*6)*7
-10*(6*8) = (-10*6)*8
-10*(6*9) = (-10*6)*9
-10*(7*-10) = (-10*7)*-10
-10*(7*-9) = (-10*7)*-9
-10*(7*-8) = (-10*7)*-8
-10*(7*-7) = (-10*7)*-7
-10*(7*-6) = (-10*7)*-6
-10*(7*-5) = (-10*7)*-5
-10*(7*-4) = (-10*7)*-4
-10*(7*-3) = (-10*7)*-3
-10*(7*-2) = (-10*7)*-2
-10*(7*-1) = (-10*7)*-1
-10*(7*1) = (-10*7)*1
-10*(7*2) = (-10*7)*2
-10*(7*3) = (-10*7)*3
-10*(7*4) = (-10*7)*4
-10*(7*5) = (-10*7)*5
-10*(7*6) = (-10*7)*6
-10*(7*7) = (-10*7)*7
-10*(7*8) = (-10*7)*8
-10*(7*9) = (-10*7)*9
-10*(8*-10) = (-10*8)*-10
-10*(8*-9) = (-10*8)*-9
-10*(8*-8) = (-10*8)*-8
-10*(8*-7) = (-10*8)*-7
-10*(8*-6) = (-10*8)*-6
-10*(8*-5) = (-10*8)*-5
-10*(8*-4) = (-10*8)*-4
-10*(8*-3) = (-10*8)*-3
-10*(8*-2) = (-10*8)*-2
-10*(8*-1) = (-10*8)*-1
-10*(8*1) = (-10*8)*1
-10*(8*2) = (-10*8)*2
-10*(8*3) = (-10*8)*3
-10*(8*4) = (-10*8)*4
-10*(8*5) = (-10*8)*5
-10*(8*6) = (-10*8)*6
-10*(8*7) = (-10*8)*7
-10*(8*8) = (-10*8)*8
-10*(8*9) = (-10*8)*9
-10*(9*-10) = (-10*9)*-10
-10*(9*-9) = (-10*9)*-9
-10*(9*-8) = (-10*9)*-8
-10*(9*-7) = (-10*9)*-7
-10*(9*-6) = (-10*9)*-6
-10*(9*-5) = (-10*9)*-5
-10*(9*-4) = (-10*9)*-4
-10*(9*-3) = (-10*9)*-3
-10*(9*-2) = (-10*9)*-2
-10*(9*-1) = (-10*9)*-1
-10*(9*1) = (-10*9)*1
-10*(9*2) = (-10*9)*2
-10*(9*3) = (-10*9)*3
-10*(9*4) = (-10*9)*4
-10*(9*5) = (-10*9)*5
-10*(9*6) = (-10*9)*6
-10*(9*7) = (-10*9)*7
-10*(9*8) = (-10*9)*8
-10*(9*9) = (-10*9)*9
-9*(-10*-10) = (-9*-10)*-10
-9*(-10*-9) = (-9*-10)*-9
-9*(-10*-8) = (-9*-10)*-8
-9*(-10*-7) = (-9*-10)*-7
-9*(-10*-6) = (-9*-10)*-6
-9*(-10*-5) = (-9*-10)*-5
-9*(-10*-4) = (-9*-10)*-4
-9*(-10*-3) = (-9*-10)*-3
-9*(-10*-2) = (-9*-10)*-2
-9*(-10*-1) = (-9*-10)*-1
-9*(-10*1) = (-9*-10)*1
-9*(-10*2) = (-9*-10)*2
-9*(-10*3) = (-9*-10)*3
-9*(-10*4) = (-9*-10)*4
-9*(-10*5) = (-9*-10)*5
-9*(-10*6) = (-9*-10)*6
-9*(-10*7) = (-9*-10)*7
-9*(-10*8) = (-9*-10)*8
-9*(-10*9) = (-9*-10)*9
-9*(-9*-10) = (-9*-9)*-10
-9*(-9*-9) = (-9*-9)*-9
-9*(-9*-8) = (-9*-9)*-8
-9*(-9*-7) = (-9*-9)*-7
-9*(-9*-6) = (-9*-9)*-6
-9*(-9*-5) = (-9*-9)*-5
-9*(-9*-4) = (-9*-9)*-4
-9*(-9*-3) = (-9*-9)*-3
-9*(-9*-2) = (-9*-9)*-2
-9*(-9*-1) = (-9*-9)*-1
-9*(-9*1) = (-9*-9)*1
-9*(-9*2) = (-9*-9)*2
-9*(-9*3) = (-9*-9)*3
-9*(-9*4) = (-9*-9)*4
-9*(-9*5) = (-9*-9)*5
-9*(-9*6) = (-9*-9)*6
-9*(-9*7) = (-9*-9)*7
-9*(-9*8) = (-9*-9)*8
-9*(-9*9) = (-9*-9)*9
-9*(-8*-10) = (-9*-8)*-10
-9*(-8*-9) = (-9*-8)*-9
-9*(-8*-8) = (-9*-8)*-8
-9*(-8*-7) = (-9*-8)*-7
-9*(-8*-6) = (-9*-8)*-6
-9*(-8*-5) = (-9*-8)*-5
-9*(-8*-4) = (-9*-8)*-4
-9*(-8*-3) = (-9*-8)*-3
-9*(-8*-2) = (-9*-8)*-2
-9*(-8*-1) = (-9*-8)*-1
-9*(-8*1) = (-9*-8)*1
-9*(-8*2) = (-9*-8)*2
-9*(-8*3) = (-9*-8)*3
-9*(-8*4) = (-9*-8)*4
-9*(-8*5) = (-9*-8)*5
-9*(-8*6) = (-9*-8)*6
-9*(-8*7) = (-9*-8)*7
-9*(-8*8) = (-9*-8)*8
-9*(-8*9) = (-9*-8)*9
-9*(-7*-10) = (-9*-7)*-10
-9*(-7*-9) = (-9*-7)*-9
-9*(-7*-8) = (-9*-7)*-8
-9*(-7*-7) = (-9*-7)*-7
-9*(-7*-6) = (-9*-7)*-6
-9*(-7*-5) = (-9*-7)*-5
-9*(-7*-4) = (-9*-7)*-4
-9*(-7*-3) = (-9*-7)*-3
-9*(-7*-2) = (-9*-7)*-2
-9*(-7*-1) = (-9*-7)*-1
-9*(-7*1) = (-9*-7)*1
-9*(-7*2) = (-9*-7)*2
-9*(-7*3) = (-9*-7)*3
-9*(-7*4) = (-9*-7)*4
-9*(-7*5) = (-9*-7)*5
-9*(-7*6) = (-9*-7)*6
-9*(-7*7) = (-9*-7)*7
-9*(-7*8) = (-9*-7)*8
-9*(-7*9) = (-9*-7)*9
-9*(-6*-10) = (-9*-6)*-10
-9*(-6*-9) = (-9*-6)*-9
-9*(-6*-8) = (-9*-6)*-8
-9*(-6*-7) = (-9*-6)*-7
-9*(-6*-6) = (-9*-6)*-6
-9*(-6*-5) = (-9*-6)*-5
-9*(-6*-4) = (-9*-6)*-4
-9*(-6*-3) = (-9*-6)*-3
-9*(-6*-2) = (-9*-6)*-2
-9*(-6*-1) = (-9*-6)*-1
-9*(-6*1) = (-9*-6)*1
-9*(-6*2) = (-9*-6)*2
-9*(-6*3) = (-9*-6)*3
-9*(-6*4) = (-9*-6)*4
-9*(-6*5) = (-9*-6)*5
-9*(-6*6) = (-9*-6)*6
-9*(-6*7) = (-9*-6)*7
-9*(-6*8) = (-9*-6)*8
-9*(-6*9) = (-9*-6)*9
-9*(-5*-10) = (-9*-5)*-10
-9*(-5*-9) = (-9*-5)*-9
-9*(-5*-8) = (-9*-5)*-8
-9*(-5*-7) = (-9*-5)*-7
-9*(-5*-6) = (-9*-5)*-6
-9*(-5*-5) = (-9*-5)*-5
-9*(-5*-4) = (-9*-5)*-4
-9*(-5*-3) = (-9*-5)*-3
-9*(-5*-2) = (-9*-5)*-2
-9*(-5*-1) = (-9*-5)*-1
-9*(-5*1) = (-9*-5)*1
-9*(-5*2) = (-9*-5)*2
-9*(-5*3) = (-9*-5)*3
-9*(-5*4) = (-9*-5)*4
-9*(-5*5) = (-9*-5)*5
-9*(-5*6) = (-9*-5)*6
-9*(-5*7) = (-9*-5)*7
-9*(-5*8) = (-9*-5)*8
-9*(-5*9) = (-9*-5)*9
-9*(-4*-10) = (-9*-4)*-10
-9*(-4*-9) = (-9*-4)*-9
-9*(-4*-8) = (-9*-4)*-8
-9*(-4*-7) = (-9*-4)*-7
-9*(-4*-6) = (-9*-4)*-6
-9*(-4*-5) = (-9*-4)*-5
-9*(-4*-4) = (-9*-4)*-4
-9*(-4*-3) = (-9*-4)*-3
-9*(-4*-2) = (-9*-4)*-2
-9*(-4*-1) = (-9*-4)*-1
-9*(-4*1) = (-9*-4)*1
-9*(-4*2) = (-9*-4)*2
-9*(-4*3) = (-9*-4)*3
-9*(-4*4) = (-9*-4)*4
-9*(-4*5) = (-9*-4)*5
-9*(-4*6) = (-9*-4)*6
-9*(-4*7) = (-9*-4)*7
-9*(-4*8) = (-9*-4)*8
-9*(-4*9) = (-9*-4)*9
-9*(-3*-10) = (-9*-3)*-10
-9*(-3*-9) = (-9*-3)*-9
-9*(-3*-8) = (-9*-3)*-8
-9*(-3*-7) = (-9*-3)*-7
-9*(-3*-6) = (-9*-3)*-6
-9*(-3*-5) = (-9*-3)*-5
-9*(-3*-4) = (-9*-3)*-4
-9*(-3*-3) = (-9*-3)*-3
-9*(-3*-2) = (-9*-3)*-2
-9*(-3*-1) = (-9*-3)*-1
-9*(-3*1) = (-9*-3)*1
-9*(-3*2) = (-9*-3)*2
-9*(-3*3) = (-9*-3)*3
-9*(-3*4) = (-9*-3)*4
-9*(-3*5) = (-9*-3)*5
-9*(-3*6) = (-9*-3)*6
-9*(-3*7) = (-9*-3)*7
-9*(-3*8) = (-9*-3)*8
-9*(-3*9) = (-9*-3)*9
-9*(-2*-10) = (-9*-2)*-10
-9*(-2*-9) = (-9*-2)*-9
-9*(-2*-8) = (-9*-2)*-8
-9*(-2*-7) = (-9*-2)*-7
-9*(-2*-6) = (-9*-2)*-6
-9*(-2*-5) = (-9*-2)*-5
-9*(-2*-4) = (-9*-2)*-4
-9*(-2*-3) = (-9*-2)*-3
-9*(-2*-2) = (-9*-2)*-2
-9*(-2*-1) = (-9*-2)*-1
-9*(-2*1) = (-9*-2)*1
-9*(-2*2) = (-9*-2)*2
-9*(-2*3) = (-9*-2)*3
-9*(-2*4) = (-9*-2)*4
-9*(-2*5) = (-9*-2)*5
-9*(-2*6) = (-9*-2)*6
-9*(-2*7) = (-9*-2)*7
-9*(-2*8) = (-9*-2)*8
-9*(-2*9) = (-9*-2)*9
-9*(-1*-10) = (-9*-1)*-10
-9*(-1*-9) = (-9*-1)*-9
-9*(-1*-8) = (-9*-1)*-8
-9*(-1*-7) = (-9*-1)*-7
-9*(-1*-6) = (-9*-1)*-6
-9*(-1*-5) = (-9*-1)*-5
-9*(-1*-4) = (-9*-1)*-4
-9*(-1*-3) = (-9*-1)*-3
-9*(-1*-2) = (-9*-1)*-2
-9*(-1*-1) = (-9*-1)*-1
-9*(-1*1) = (-9*-1)*1
-9*(-1*2) = (-9*-1)*2
-9*(-1*3) = (-9*-1)*3
-9*(-1*4) = (-9*-1)*4
-9*(-1*5) = (-9*-1)*5
-9*(-1*6) = (-9*-1)*6
-9*(-1*7) = (-9*-1)*7
-9*(-1*8) = (-9*-1)*8
-9*(-1*9) = (-9*-1)*9
-9*(1*-10) = (-9*1)*-10
-9*(1*-9) = (-9*1)*-9
-9*(1*-8) = (-9*1)*-8
-9*(1*-7) = (-9*1)*-7
-9*(1*-6) = (-9*1)*-6
-9*(1*-5) = (-9*1)*-5
-9*(1*-4) = (-9*1)*-4
-9*(1*-3) = (-9*1)*-3
-9*(1*-2) = (-9*1)*-2
-9*(1*-1) = (-9*1)*-1
-9*(1*1) = (-9*1)*1
-9*(1*2) = (-9*1)*2
-9*(1*3) = (-9*1)*3
-9*(1*4) = (-9*1)*4
-9*(1*5) = (-9*1)*5
-9*(1*6) = (-9*1)*6
-9*(1*7) = (-9*1)*7
-9*(1*8) = (-9*1)*8
-9*(1*9) = (-9*1)*9
-9*(2*-10) = (-9*2)*-10
-9*(2*-9) = (-9*2)*-9
-9*(2*-8) = (-9*2)*-8
-9*(2*-7) = (-9*2)*-7
-9*(2*-6) = (-9*2)*-6
-9*(2*-5) = (-9*2)*-5
-9*(2*-4) = (-9*2)*-4
-9*(2*-3) = (-9*2)*-3
-9*(2*-2) = (-9*2)*-2
-9*(2*-1) = (-9*2)*-1
-9*(2*1) = (-9*2)*1
-9*(2*2) = (-9*2)*2
-9*(2*3) = (-9*2)*3
-9*(2*4) = (-9*2)*4
-9*(2*5) = (-9*2)*5
-9*(2*6) = (-9*2)*6
-9*(2*7) = (-9*2)*7
-9*(2*8) = (-9*2)*8
-9*(2*9) = (-9*2)*9
-9*(3*-10) = (-9*3)*-10
-9*(3*-9) = (-9*3)*-9
-9*(3*-8) = (-9*3)*-8
-9*(3*-7) = (-9*3)*-7
-9*(3*-6) = (-9*3)*-6
-9*(3*-5) = (-9*3)*-5
-9*(3*-4) = (-9*3)*-4
-9*(3*-3) = (-9*3)*-3
-9*(3*-2) = (-9*3)*-2
-9*(3*-1) = (-9*3)*-1
-9*(3*1) = (-9*3)*1
-9*(3*2) = (-9*3)*2
-9*(3*3) = (-9*3)*3
-9*(3*4) = (-9*3)*4
-9*(3*5) = (-9*3)*5
-9*(3*6) = (-9*3)*6
-9*(3*7) = (-9*3)*7
-9*(3*8) = (-9*3)*8
-9*(3*9) = (-9*3)*9
-9*(4*-10) = (-9*4)*-10
-9*(4*-9) = (-9*4)*-9
-9*(4*-8) = (-9*4)*-8
-9*(4*-7) = (-9*4)*-7
-9*(4*-6) = (-9*4)*-6
-9*(4*-5) = (-9*4)*-5
-9*(4*-4) = (-9*4)*-4
-9*(4*-3) = (-9*4)*-3
-9*(4*-2) = (-9*4)*-2
-9*(4*-1) = (-9*4)*-1
-9*(4*1) = (-9*4)*1
-9*(4*2) = (-9*4)*2
-9*(4*3) = (-9*4)*3
-9*(4*4) = (-9*4)*4
-9*(4*5) = (-9*4)*5
-9*(4*6) = (-9*4)*6
-9*(4*7) = (-9*4)*7
-9*(4*8) = (-9*4)*8
-9*(4*9) = (-9*4)*9
-9*(5*-10) = (-9*5)*-10
-9*(5*-9) = (-9*5)*-9
-9*(5*-8) = (-9*5)*-8
-9*(5*-7) = (-9*5)*-7
-9*(5*-6) = (-9*5)*-6
-9*(5*-5) = (-9*5)*-5
-9*(5*-4) = (-9*5)*-4
-9*(5*-3) = (-9*5)*-3
-9*(5*-2) = (-9*5)*-2
-9*(5*-1) = (-9*5)*-1
-9*(5*1) = (-9*5)*1
-9*(5*2) = (-9*5)*2
-9*(5*3) = (-9*5)*3
-9*(5*4) = (-9*5)*4
-9*(5*5) = (-9*5)*5
-9*(5*6) = (-9*5)*6
-9*(5*7) = (-9*5)*7
-9*(5*8) = (-9*5)*8
-9*(5*9) = (-9*5)*9
-9*(6*-10) = (-9*6)*-10
-9*(6*-9) = (-9*6)*-9
-9*(6*-8) = (-9*6)*-8
-9*(6*-7) = (-9*6)*-7
-9*(6*-6) = (-9*6)*-6
-9*(6*-5) = (-9*6)*-5
-9*(6*-4) = (-9*6)*-4
-9*(6*-3) = (-9*6)*-3
-9*(6*-2) = (-9*6)*-2
-9*(6*-1) = (-9*6)*-1
-9*(6*1) = (-9*6)*1
-9*(6*2) = (-9*6)*2
-9*(6*3) = (-9*6)*3
-9*(6*4) = (-9*6)*4
-9*(6*5) = (-9*6)*5
-9*(6*6) = (-9*6)*6
-9*(6*7) = (-9*6)*7
-9*(6*8) = (-9*6)*8
-9*(6*9) = (-9*6)*9
-9*(7*-10) = (-9*7)*-10
-9*(7*-9) = (-9*7)*-9
-9*(7*-8) = (-9*7)*-8
-9*(7*-7) = (-9*7)*-7
-9*(7*-6) = (-9*7)*-6
-9*(7*-5) = (-9*7)*-5
-9*(7*-4) = (-9*7)*-4
-9*(7*-3) = (-9*7)*-3
-9*(7*-2) = (-9*7)*-2
-9*(7*-1) = (-9*7)*-1
-9*(7*1) = (-9*7)*1
-9*(7*2) = (-9*7)*2
-9*(7*3) = (-9*7)*3
-9*(7*4) = (-9*7)*4
-9*(7*5) = (-9*7)*5
-9*(7*6) = (-9*7)*6
-9*(7*7) = (-9*7)*7
-9*(7*8) = (-9*7)*8
-9*(7*9) = (-9*7)*9
-9*(8*-10) = (-9*8)*-10
-9*(8*-9) = (-9*8)*-9
-9*(8*-8) = (-9*8)*-8
-9*(8*-7) = (-9*8)*-7
-9*(8*-6) = (-9*8)*-6
-9*(8*-5) = (-9*8)*-5
-9*(8*-4) = (-9*8)*-4
-9*(8*-3) = (-9*8)*-3
-9*(8*-2) = (-9*8)*-2
-9*(8*-1) = (-9*8)*-1
-9*(8*1) = (-9*8)*1
-9*(8*2) = (-9*8)*2
-9*(8*3) = (-9*8)*3
-9*(8*4) = (-9*8)*4
-9*(8*5) = (-9*8)*5
-9*(8*6) = (-9*8)*6
-9*(8*7) = (-9*8)*7
-9*(8*8) = (-9*8)*8
-9*(8*9) = (-9*8)*9
-9*(9*-10) = (-9*9)*-10
-9*(9*-9) = (-9*9)*-9
-9*(9*-8) = (-9*9)*-8
-9*(9*-7) = (-9*9)*-7
-9*(9*-6) = (-9*9)*-6
-9*(9*-5) = (-9*9)*-5
-9*(9*-4) = (-9*9)*-4
-9*(9*-3) = (-9*9)*-3
-9*(9*-2) = (-9*9)*-2
-9*(9*-1) = (-9*9)*-1
-9*(9*1) = (-9*9)*1
-9*(9*2) = (-9*9)*2
-9*(9*3) = (-9*9)*3
-9*(9*4) = (-9*9)*4
-9*(9*5) = (-9*9)*5
-9*(9*6) = (-9*9)*6
-9*(9*7) = (-9*9)*7
-9*(9*8) = (-9*9)*8
-9*(9*9) = (-9*9)*9
-8*(-10*-10) = (-8*-10)*-10
-8*(-10*-9) = (-8*-10)*-9
-8*(-10*-8) = (-8*-10)*-8
-8*(-10*-7) = (-8*-10)*-7
-8*(-10*-6) = (-8*-10)*-6
-8*(-10*-5) = (-8*-10)*-5
-8*(-10*-4) = (-8*-10)*-4
-8*(-10*-3) = (-8*-10)*-3
-8*(-10*-2) = (-8*-10)*-2
-8*(-10*-1) = (-8*-10)*-1
-8*(-10*1) = (-8*-10)*1
-8*(-10*2) = (-8*-10)*2
-8*(-10*3) = (-8*-10)*3
-8*(-10*4) = (-8*-10)*4
-8*(-10*5) = (-8*-10)*5
-8*(-10*6) = (-8*-10)*6
-8*(-10*7) = (-8*-10)*7
-8*(-10*8) = (-8*-10)*8
-8*(-10*9) = (-8*-10)*9
-8*(-9*-10) = (-8*-9)*-10
-8*(-9*-9) = (-8*-9)*-9
-8*(-9*-8) = (-8*-9)*-8
-8*(-9*-7) = (-8*-9)*-7
-8*(-9*-6) = (-8*-9)*-6
-8*(-9*-5) = (-8*-9)*-5
-8*(-9*-4) = (-8*-9)*-4
-8*(-9*-3) = (-8*-9)*-3
-8*(-9*-2) = (-8*-9)*-2
-8*(-9*-1) = (-8*-9)*-1
-8*(-9*1) = (-8*-9)*1
-8*(-9*2) = (-8*-9)*2
-8*(-9*3) = (-8*-9)*3
-8*(-9*4) = (-8*-9)*4
-8*(-9*5) = (-8*-9)*5
-8*(-9*6) = (-8*-9)*6
-8*(-9*7) = (-8*-9)*7
-8*(-9*8) = (-8*-9)*8
-8*(-9*9) = (-8*-9)*9
-8*(-8*-10) = (-8*-8)*-10
-8*(-8*-9) = (-8*-8)*-9
-8*(-8*-8) = (-8*-8)*-8
-8*(-8*-7) = (-8*-8)*-7
-8*(-8*-6) = (-8*-8)*-6
-8*(-8*-5) = (-8*-8)*-5
-8*(-8*-4) = (-8*-8)*-4
-8*(-8*-3) = (-8*-8)*-3
-8*(-8*-2) = (-8*-8)*-2
-8*(-8*-1) = (-8*-8)*-1
-8*(-8*1) = (-8*-8)*1
-8*(-8*2) = (-8*-8)*2
-8*(-8*3) = (-8*-8)*3
-8*(-8*4) = (-8*-8)*4
-8*(-8*5) = (-8*-8)*5
-8*(-8*6) = (-8*-8)*6
-8*(-8*7) = (-8*-8)*7
-8*(-8*8) = (-8*-8)*8
-8*(-8*9) = (-8*-8)*9
-8*(-7*-10) = (-8*-7)*-10
-8*(-7*-9) = (-8*-7)*-9
-8*(-7*-8) = (-8*-7)*-8
-8*(-7*-7) = (-8*-7)*-7
-8*(-7*-6) = (-8*-7)*-6
-8*(-7*-5) = (-8*-7)*-5
-8*(-7*-4) = (-8*-7)*-4
-8*(-7*-3) = (-8*-7)*-3
-8*(-7*-2) = (-8*-7)*-2
-8*(-7*-1) = (-8*-7)*-1
-8*(-7*1) = (-8*-7)*1
-8*(-7*2) = (-8*-7)*2
-8*(-7*3) = (-8*-7)*3
-8*(-7*4) = (-8*-7)*4
-8*(-7*5) = (-8*-7)*5
-8*(-7*6) = (-8*-7)*6
-8*(-7*7) = (-8*-7)*7
-8*(-7*8) = (-8*-7)*8
-8*(-7*9) = (-8*-7)*9
-8*(-6*-10) = (-8*-6)*-10
-8*(-6*-9) = (-8*-6)*-9
-8*(-6*-8) = (-8*-6)*-8
```

I can't seem to prove it using the above formula, but there is another round about way using symmetric difference of divisor sets.  Each element $a \in \Bbb{Z}\setminus 0$ is self-inverting.

Therefore $(\Bbb{Z}\setminus 0, \star, 1)$ forms an abelian group.  So let's denote it with $\oplus = \star$ to be in additive notation.

---

**Question.** Can the integers form a field $(\Bbb{Z}, \oplus, \cdot)$ for some kind of $\cdot$ multiplication, or a ring $(\Bbb{Z}, +', \star)$ for some addition $+'$ that I'm not sure how to define?

Comment: damn bro, I love hwo you post your conjectures everyday on this site. Maybe you will win fields or somethign one day

Comment: I laughed. Not because the question was funny. But because you thought that I would find it funny, which I didn't. The irony is strong with this one.

Comment: @HopefulWhitepiller Thanks bro!  I bet there's at least one elementary proof that can be made by a crackpot, that all the professionals just happened to miss.  We never searched "all of math" throughout history.  These are facts.

Comment: Would that constitute a logical paradox? @AdamRubinson

Comment: Would considering characteristics be useful? Given that we have characteristic 0, then we'll necessarily have a homomorphism from $\mathbb Q$ into our potential field. Note also the addition would need to be a group for the whole of our field - so $(\Bbb{Z}, \oplus, \cdot)$ wouldn't work.

Comment: @George if you have an answer for either of my two questions, feel free to make a post.  Make sure to include proofs

Comment: @George That's a good question.  IDK! :)

Comment: I'm just saying addition is on the whole field, where the $\oplus$ would be  invertible only on $\Bbb{Z} \setminus 0$, so we can exclude the first case. It doesn't feel substantial enough to be an answer, since it doesn't consider the case of this operation being the multiplication.

Comment: Since $\operatorname{lcm}(a, b) \operatorname{gcd}(a, b)$, you may as well write the operation more symmetrically as $a \star b := \frac{\operatorname{lcm}(a, b)}{\operatorname{gcd}(a, b)}$, which arguably makes more apparent some of its properties.

Comment: In my previous comment the first equation should be $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)=ab$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, $4 \ast 2=\frac{8}{4}=2=1 \ast 2$, so $\ast$ can’t be a group law.

Comment: Aha!  Then it's a group on the squarefree integers.... ?

Comment: Yes, in fact. You can define a bijection $f$ from the square-free integers to the set of finite subsets of $\mathbb{P} \cup \{-1\}$, by mapping $n$ to the set of primes dividing $n$ (and adding $-1$ when $n<0$). Then $f$ maps $\ast$ to the symmetric difference, which is a group law (and then intersection – aka a slight modification of gcd on the integers, by saying that $-1$ divides $n$ iff $n<0$ – makes that a ring). Such a ring is a well-known case of *Boolean ring*.

Comment: Correction: you don’t actually get a *ring*, because gcd has no neutral element!

Comment: Offhand it looks like we can identify resulting group with $\Bbb Q^\times / (\Bbb Q^\times)^2$ with the map induced by multiplication on $\Bbb Q^\times$.